# Controlling ActiveX Control via Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, activex, wonderware

I am trying to use some software from WonderWare via ActiveX. I have gotten the object to appear, but I am want to pass some parameters to it and eliminate having to setup the object everytime. There are two versions of the control ActiveX and .NET. I haven't gotten the .NET control to work at all, but I can get the ActiveX one / just not the parameters.

Here is what the manual says about it:

> The aaHistClientTrend control allows you to run the Wonderware
>   Historian Client Trend program (or a functional subset) from within
>   the Wonderware InTouch HMI software or a .NET container like Visual
>   Basic .NET or Internet Explorer.

The HTML code that I have:

```
<html>
<head>
<body>
   <object id="aTrend1" classid="clsid:E08609F1-58CC-11D3-B1CF-00105AA45077" viewastext="" height="100%" width="100%" />
</body>
</head>
</html>
```

I try to pass the parameter via:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
    document.aTrend1.TagPickerVisible = false; 
</script>
```

And it crashes internet explorer.

**EDIT : Any ideas?**

Comment: TagPickerVisible isn't a property of this object. The attached code lists its members and methods.

 `var d = [];
    for(var i in document.aTrend1)
        d.push(i);
    d.sort(function(a,b){return a > b});
    for(var i  = 0; i < d.length; i++)
        console.log(d[i]);`

Comment: Are you saying to run that command and it will list the available members and methods? If so where is the console.log stored so I can see a list?

Comment: console.log() is a firefox firebug extension method. If you don't use firebug you could always replace the console call with write or some other means of writing to the document.

Comment: I installed firebug, but I don't know how to copy and paste the console.log, it doesn't paste well. I don't really know what I am looking at. In the manual it has TagPickerVisible listed and in a "working" javascript that a vendor installed, that parameter is working. I just can't replicate it. There is a good bit of that code and it's complicated. I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a way to do it. Not sure it's the only way, but it works.

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function fxnTrend()
    {
    aTrend1.ToolBarVisible = false; 
    aTrend1.TagPickerVisible = false; 
    aTrend1.RealTimeMode = true;
    aTrend1.TimeBarVisible = false;
    aTrend1.GridVisible = false;
    }
    fxnTrend();
</script>

<body onLoad="fxnTrend()">
    <object id="aTrend1" classid="clsid:E08609F1-58CC-11D3-B1CF-00105AA45077" viewastext="" height="100%" width="100%" />
</body>
</head>
</html>
```